Unable to create superuser after creating CustomUser
After creating Custom user when i tried to create a superuser it gave error
TypeError: UserManager.create_superuser() missing 1 required positional argument: 'username'
Then after creating CustomUserManager its showing
Expression of type "CustomUserManager" is incompatible with declared type "UserManager[Self@AbstractUser]"
"CustomUserManager" is incompatible with "UserManager[Self@AbstractUser]"
Expression of type "CustomUserManager" is incompatible with declared type "UserManager[Self@AbstractUser]"
  "CustomUserManager" is incompatible with "UserManager[Self@AbstractUser]"


class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The Email field must be set')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        return self.create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)


class CustomUser(AbstractUser, PermissionsMixin):
    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)  

    daily_reminders = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    start_at = models.TimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    end_at = models.TimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    notification_status = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    device_type = models.CharField(choices=DIV_CHOICES, max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
    device_token = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    categories = models.JSONField(default=list, null=True, blank=True)
    

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'  
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []  
    
    objects = CustomUserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email


I BaseUserManager imported
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import BaseUserManager


but still showing error

Did you set REQUIRED_FIELDS?

There is no problem with the code.
However, the database migration probably has UserManager applied.
Makemigrations and migrate process are also required when you change the Manager.
python3 manage.py makemigrations YourUserApp
python3 manage.py migrate

CustomUserManager has not yet been applied, Please try again after doing the migrations!
